# GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions setting access_type as offline

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I'm trying to obtain Refresh token for Google Account using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google in MVC5 project. To obtain RefreshToken in resposne from google server, I need to set `access_type = offline`. But I can't find any suitable property in `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions` object for that.

Code using to allow authentication

```
        var gao = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GoogleClientId"),
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("GoogleClientSecret"),
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async ctx =>
                {
                    var refreshToken = ctx.RefreshToken;
                    //ctx.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", refreshToken));                    
                }
            }
        };

        gao.Scope.Add(TasksService.Scope.Tasks);
        gao.Scope.Add("openid");

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(gao);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Release 3.0.0 of the Microsoft.Owin.Security library will be adding this option to the GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider (see fixed [issue #227](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/workitem/227)). According to [Katana Project roadmap](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=roadmap) it will be available late summer 2014. If you need this ability before the official release you can get the latest build through the pre-release NuGet channel.

You can then configure it like so (in Startup.Auth.cs):

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions {
    ClientId = ...,
    ClientSecret = ...,
    AccessType = "offline",
    Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider {
        OnAuthenticated = context => {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.RefreshToken)) {
                context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("RefreshToken", context.RefreshToken));
            }
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    });
```

And you can obtain the refresh token in ExternalLoginCallback (AccountController.cs if you kept the default code organization):

```
string refreshToken = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims
    .Where(i => i.Type == "RefreshToken")
    .Select(i => i.Value)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: To those who stumble upon this. You need to revoke the app and go to consent screen again to get this refresh token.

Answer (score 3):

There is NO way to do this in current version of Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google assembly.
But because of the fact, that library is open source you can modify it in the way to get refresh token.

As I said, google oauth2.0 needs to have setted property `access_type` to `offline`. You can achieve this adding one static line (to has this property setted each time - not the best solution, but as fast one time fix it works) in `GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler` method `ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()` as adding query string `AddQueryString(queryStrings, properties, "access_type", "offline")`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there *is* a way of doing this! I've done something similar with the "login_hint" querystring element.

When you declare the provider you can register an OnApplyRedirect handler and change the URL there:

```
this.Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnApplyRedirect = async context =>
                {
                    string redirect = context.RedirectUri;

                    // Change the value of "redirect" here
                    // e.g. append access_type=offline

                    context.Response.Redirect(redirect);
                },
            OnAuthenticated = async context =>
            {
                // Do stuff
            }
        };
```

Comment: Though, thinking about it some more, you should probably be using a service account if you require offline access..

Comment: This worked for me.  In what scenarios should you be doing this vs using a service account?  I need to get an access and refresh token so I can access user's google analytics accounts offline every day to process their data and I'm using OAuth for them to grant me permission.  Thanks!